# change an active Kubernetes cluster cotroller node IP address

Tags: kubernetes

Recently there was a problem with the network environment, the local virtual machine built Kubernetes environment does not have a fixed IP, so the node IP changed. I could request to the network admin to preserve the old IP as well as the new IP but they cannot do this forever. Since there are critical services up in the cluster so I cannot reset the cluster and init a new white empty clean cluster. I read [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338#issuecomment-418879755) comment and do its commends step by step but all of the cluster main services (such as kubelet) were down and I got a `connection refused` error.
after I do the step

```
# find all the config map names
configmaps=$(kubectl -n kube-system get cm -o name | \
  awk '{print $1}' | \
  cut -d '/' -f 2)

# fetch all for filename reference
dir=$(mktemp -d)
for cf in $configmaps; do
  kubectl -n kube-system get cm $cf -o yaml > $dir/$cf.yaml
done

# have grep help you find the files to edit, and where
grep -Hn $dir/* -e $oldip

# edit those files, in my case, grep only returned these two:
kubectl -n kube-system edit cm kubeadm-config
kubectl -n kube-system edit cm kube-proxy
```

there are no changes in the certificate sections in the files. There is no hostname and I use the IP address in all of the config files both in the controller node and worker nodes. It would be good to notice that as in the comment I put my new IP address in the `newip` variable and the old one in the `oldip` variable.